# Using conjunction "while" as an archaic prepositonal form for "until"

Tags: prepositions, dialects, poetry, archaicisms

In my *Penguin English Dictionary*, I've encountered the word *while* marked as an archaic form for the preposition *until*. Furthermore, according to my online research, [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/while) states that it is a Northern England dialect.

For me, as an non-native speaker and someone who is interested in poetry, it is a little bit confusing, and therefore I have two questions:

- Is it still used exclusively as a Northern England dialect, or it is an archaic word (which could be used in poetry)?
- And if it's an archaic (literally) word, would it fit into the following concept: **While the end of time.?**

Comment: I would think if *until* was a form of *while*, that it would be the **negative** form.  Aside: some programming languages have these two as keywords, and `while(p)` is equivalent to `until(!p)`

Comment: OED's most recent citation for the usage is *1872   J. Hartley's **Yorkshire Ditties** 2nd Ser. 17   We blushed **wol** us faces wor all in a blaze*, under the definition identified as *Now dial. (chiefly north.)*. If you don't live in a linguistic community where it's still used (vanishingly unlikely), I would strongly suggest you *don't* try to "re-introduce" the usage. Almost no-one will understand it, and I can see no possible advantage in promoting this effectively defunct dialectal form.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it still used exclusively as a Northern England dialect"
I would say that it is used in parts of Northern England.
It is used widely in Sheffield. Not Manchester or Liverpool though.
Typical usage:
Q: when's the party?
A: four while eight

Answer (score 0):

Very archaic and would be confusing to an American English speaker's ear. "While" in a chronological sense happens before "until" arrives.

"I will long while I wait until you love in return."

Comment: This really isn't an answer to the questions asked. All you are confirming is about American English, not about Northern England English.